# Scrollable plot vistime in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, vistime

Is it possible to fix the height of a plot in vistime and then be able to scroll through the rows rather than having all rows presented at once. I know you can fix the zoom since it's a plotly object, but once zoomed in it does not seem like its possible to scroll down to see the other rows.

Comment: What have you tried? Please add some code.

Comment: Right now I have:                                                                                           `vistime(data, 
        col.event = "group", 
        col.group = "id", 
        title = "Questionnaires")%>% plotly::layout(xaxis=list(fixedrange=TRUE))` so I am able to fix the x axis, but I am not able to scroll when zoomed.

Comment: I found this page: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-add-vertical-scroll-bar-on-horizontal-bar-chart/12342 but I cannot seem to find the corresponding syntax for r